# I want to write a program in python for Square and taking input from csv file

Tags: python, csv

When i tried to run this code, i got these error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "txt_square.py", line 7, in <module>`enter code here`  
   sqr = [elem **2 for elem in sqr_lst]
   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'

import csv
import math

with open('/home/amankumar/test.csv', 'rb') as fl:
    reader = csv.reader(fl)
    sqr_lst = list(reader)
    sqr = [elem **2 for elem in sqr_lst]
print sqr
```

Answer (score 3):

A csv reader object contains the rows which are list of the items, and as the error says you can not use `**` operand for a list and integer. If you want to do this operation between the items you need to loop over the rows.

You can us a *list comprehension* :

```
sqrs = [[i **2 for for i in elem] for elem in sqr_lst ]
```

Then the result would be a nested list of sqr of all items (each nested list is a row)

Comment: If you do it exactly like that, then `sqr` will be just the last row squared.

Comment: @tobias_k In that case OP should print the sqr in each iteration or save them, but as as more pythonic way I suggested a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what is happening here,

if you iterate over  reader(in your code) this will return you list of list of str like this :-

> [['5'], ['6'], ['7'], ['8'], ['9'], ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']]

so you can simply use this set of code `[int(i[0])**2 for i in reader]`

or you can apply any checks you require in list comprehension.